# Can't grasp MiniMax diagram (no alpha beta pruning)

Tags: minimax

[image: minimaxQuestion]

The image is one of many similar exam questions can anyone pelase help me understand it fully?

'Internal node': This is simply every node except A?

Move choices: His only options are B, C and D for this move?

Focusing on B: E=8 F=4 and G are all opponent responses, therefore they will pick the minimum value.

Now my confusion, are M N and P your known responses in the case the opponent picks G, so you should pick M=0 (the highest value), so then G gets passed 0 which the opponent should choose so B has a h-value of 0?

Are the correct value then B=0, C=1 and D=2 so pick D as next move?

Comment: "Internal nodes" are all nodes other than leaf nodes (where leaf nodes are those at the "end", those which no longer have branches growing under them). So A is also an internal node, and you should therefore also list the value assigned to node A. Other than that, everything you already wrote seems to be correct yes.